# Rewrite URL /YYYY/MM/blog-article-title to /blog/blog-article-title

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite the Blog-Urls of my Wordpress installation from

http://www.example.com/2016/11/title-of-blog-article

to

http://www.example.com/blog/title-of-blog-article

I have tried numerous RewriteRules but I don't get it.

This is what I have tried:

```
RewriteRule ^/[0-9]+/[0-9]+/(.+)$ blog/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I dont get it why it does not function... :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!
My failure was the trailing slash with

```
RewriteRule ^[0-9]+/[0-9]+/(.+)$ /blog/$1 [R=301,L]
```

it works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^/[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/(.*)$ /blog/$1 [R=301,L]
```

try this